# hexdump function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

With below python code

```
zero = '00000000000000000000000000000000'
print(bytes.fromhex(zero))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

three = '33333333333333333333333333333333'
print(bytes.fromhex(three))
b'3333333333333333
```

On printing bytes.fromhex(zero), exact 32 character is printed in hexadecimal.

But while printing bytes.fromhex(three), only 16 character is printed. zero and three string both are of same length:32

Comment: It's just the display. `chr(0x33)` is the ASCII character "3" and Python prints this as an ASCII character. `chr(0x44)` is "D" and so `print(bytes.fromhex('003344'))` will give you the output `b'\x003D'`. - tl;dr: `b'3' == b'\x33'` is `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `fromhex(string)` returns a bytes object, decoding the given string object. The string must contain two hexadecimal digits per byte, with ASCII whitespace being ignored.

It means the method read one-byte hex string `"33"` as ASCII code and `33` in ASCII code represents number 3.

Try `"34343434"` or `"32323232"`. You will see `4444` or `2222`.

Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html